# How to load UIImage from folder in assets library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apple-watch

I am trying to load an image from my XCode assets library:

[image]

Using this code:

`[self.imgIcon setImage[UIImage imageNamed:@"symptoms/anxious.buz"]];`

It works if I don't have the asset in a folder in the assets library. I've also tried renaming it to .png, as well as using 'symptoms.anxious.buz'. Because it works without a folder, I suspect there is some special way to form the path to indicate you want to look inside a folder.

What is the proper grammar for loading an asset from inside a folder of the assets library?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of code. Just copy and paste the text into the text editor and format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the name of the folder to be part of the image name then you need to tick the `Provides Namespace` option on the folder in the asset catalog...

[image]

Otherwise you can just use the asset name without the folder. So in your case...

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"anxious.buz"]
```

Comment: Oh my goodness! How ridiculously simple and yet not-so-obvious! Thank you!